# k8s pod log for "/var/log/maillog" is big to disabled it's machine

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I created pod on k8s cluster, and found pod is killed and it's Linux mahcine is failed to ssh login.
when I restart the k8s node, I found the nodes home path is used for 90%. And I found the pod's log for `/val/log/maillog` is used 3T,why?

```
pwd

/home/docker/runtime/overlay/c5b8d2bd508ab41057d151aebc55cee707a44a704cbddba268ec929ff7e80542/upper/var/log
```

```
du -sh *

2.9T    maillog 
4.0K    messages
```

```
tail -n 2 maillog

> Apr 10 23:19:15 visbox1 04-10T23:19:15.417908+08:00 visbox1
> 04-10T23:19:15.417846+08:00 visbox1 04-10T23:19:15.417789+08:00
> visbox1 04-10T23:19:15.417734+08:00 visbox1
> 04-10T23:19:15.417675+08:00 visbox1 04-10T23:19:15.417582+08:00
> visbox1 04-10T23:19:15.417526+08:00 visbox1
> 04-10T23:19:15.417467+08:00 visbox1 04-10T23:19:15.417409+08:00
> visbox1 04-10T23:19:15.417355+08:00 visbox1
> 04-10T23:19:15.417300+08:00 visbox1 04-10T23:19:15.417243+08:00
> visbox1 04-10T23:19:15.417149+08:00 visbox1
> 04-10T23:19:15.417091+08:00 visbox1 04-10T23:19:15.417035+08:00
> visbox1 04-10T23:19:15.416978+08:00 visbox1
> 04-10T23:19:15.416920+08:00 visbox1 04-10T23:19:15.416858+08:00
> visbox1 04-10T23:19:15.416796+08:00 visbox1
> 04-10T23:19:15.416739+08:00 visbox1 04-10T23:19:15.416684+08:00
> visbox1 04-10T23:19:15.416627+08:00 visbox1
> 04-10T23:19:15.416574+08:00 visbox1 04-10T23:19:15.416507+08:00
```

the visbox1 is the name of pod

Comment: Is this large log file being created from scratch, or is it simply an old log that has continually been appended to? You need to provide more context. The simple fact that a large file exists on your machine is not enough to go off of.

Comment: It is a log file being created from the pod inside, not a old log file, but i do not known why it is created; And  it will be quickly full in some minutes; When I delete this log file, it cannot be created automaticly!

Comment: Could you please add yaml of the pod to your question?

Comment: Firstly, I may tell my use case；My users login the pod container and used it as a vm, and users installed some Software but not installing the email server; I think it maybe some other server is failed, so syslog send email info to the maillog. While I cann't find the failed sever;So the yaml is not useful.